# syntax error in INSERT INTO statement, checked with space already

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was trying to run this following SQL through vba, however, it keeps telling there is a syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Can anyone help with it? Thanks a lot.

```
Dim strTemp2 As String

strTemp2 = "INSERT INTO tblPartDocs(idsPartDocID, idsScanID, intPartNum, strShopOrder/LotBatchID, dtmDateOfWork) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.tboScanID & "','" & Me.tboScanID & "','" & Me.tboPartNumber & "','" & Me.tboShop & "','" & Me.tboDateOfWork & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL strTemp2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is here

```
"strShopOrder/LotBatchI"
```

You are require to provide comma instead of forward slash

Comment: But this is one of the fields name

Comment: Never mind. Looks like even though access allow users to set name with forward slash, vba doesn't allow us to use forward slash. Thank you very much!!!! And thanks for quick reply.